# 'Permission Denied' even while running as root

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple bash shell script:

```
user_exists=cat /etc/passwd | grep 'GNU Mailman'
echo $user_exists
```

when I run this script with `sudo ./'script_name'`, I get a permission denied error on the line where I attempt to access */etc/passwd*.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the file permissions? Like a ls -la output for the file?

Comment: That command sets `$user_exists` to `"cat"` and then tries to execute `/etc/passwd` as a command, which is not what you want. The `cat is not necessary, since `grep` already knows how to read input from a file: `user_exists=$(grep 'GNU Mailman' /etc/passwd)`

Answer (score 3):

To understand why, you have to look at the line the way that `bash` looks at the line:

```
user_exists=cat /etc/passwd | grep 'GNU Mailman'
```

According to bash, you are (temporarily) setting the environment variable `user_exists` to have the value `cat`.  With that value set, then the program `/etc/passwd` is executed and its output sent to `grep 'GNU Mailman'`.  Since `/etc/passwd` does not have execute permission, this command fails for lack of permission.

The solution is to use the proper format for process substitution as outlined by Vladimir Kolesnikov:

```
user_exist=$(grep 'GNU Mailman' /etc/passwd)
```

Answer (score 2):

`user_exists=$(cat /etc/passwd | grep 'GNU Mailman')`

or better yet,

`getent passwd username`

Comment: +1 for the `getent` approach (though I think in the OP's case the lookup is being expected to match on field 5 -- "real" name text -- not on username, but username is the better practice approach, and using `getent` works with far more backends -- NIS, LDAP, etc).